Ansible: PowerShell error "Cannot connect to CIM server. Illegal execution attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion" when async
I am working on a PowerShell script in Ansible that is suppose to remove and re-add an IP address so it switches from DHCP to static. The command runs fine when it runs non-async but it needs to run async in order to reconnect properly.
This is a sample of what I am attempting, does anyone have suggestions of what I can try?
- name: set static IP
  script: |
    try{
    Remove-NetIPAddress -IPAddress 1234 -Confirm:$false
    }catch{
    Add-Content -Path $logfile -Value $_.Excpetion.Message
    }
  async: 100
  poll: 0

- name: wait for network interface back up
  load_action:
    module: wait_for

I'm not even sure why I'm even getting an error about CIM server
Cannot connect to CIM server. Illegal execution attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion

